# If $L_A:(\mathbb{R}^2, \| \cdot \|_p) \to (\mathbb{R}^3, \| \cdot \|_p )$ is an isometry, is set of columns of $A$ orthonormal?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, orthogonality

Let $p\in [1,\infty)$.
Given a $3\times 2$ matrix $A$, let $L_A:(\mathbb{R}^2, \| \cdot \|_p) \to (\mathbb{R}^3, \| \cdot \|_p )$ be an operator defined by $L_A(z) = Az$.

> Question: If $L_A$ is an isometry, does it mean that the set of columns of $A$ form an orthonormal set?

Since $L_A$ is an isometry, by considering $L_A(1,0)^T$ and $L_A(0,1)^T$, clearly the set of columns of $A$ has norm $1$.
However, I am not able to prove that they are orthogonal.
Clearly the question has positive answer if $p=2$ as one can use inner product induced by the norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ to show that the columns of $A$ are orthogonal.
It would be good if there is a reference for this fact, if it is true.

---

Remark: Let $(a_{11},a_{21}, a_{31})^T, (a_{12},a_{22}, a_{32})^T$ be the two columns of $A$.
We say that $\{(a_{11},a_{21}, a_{31})^T, (a_{12},a_{22}, a_{32})^T\}$ is orthonormal if $\|(a_{11},a_{21}, a_{31})\|_p = \|(a_{12},a_{22}, a_{32})\|_p = 1$ and $a_{11}a_{12} + a_{21}a_{22} + a_{31}a_{32}= 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by orthonormal (or orthogonal) if $p\neq 2$?

Comment: @user10354138 I added the definition of orthonormality in my post.

Comment: What do you mean by dot product?

Comment: @user10354138 edited.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you give a proof of that?  It is true that $p$-norm isometries are signed permutations (so are Euclidean isometries), but for isometric embeddings?

Comment: Ignore my comment please.